# Twitter Connect Get Auth Code Without Refreshing the Source Page

Tags: api, twitter

Is there any way with Twitter to get the auth code without having to go through Twitter and being redirected back to the source page ( my website ) ?

I am aksing this because we need to connect the user to Twitter, but without refreshing the current page the user is on.

Is this possible with Javascript, jQuery or whatever?

PLease help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using whatever, Python and Java in this case. I ran into this article a few days ago you'll find interesting:

[Automated Browserless OAuth Authentication for Twitter](http://blog.databigbang.com/automated-browserless-oauth-authentication-for-twitter/)

quote from the article:

> This article describes how to use the OAuth 3-legged protocol with a
>   headless browser like HtmlUnit to get tokens from twitter without user
>   intervention.

Comment: Auto-authorizing an application for a user who is logged into Twitter goes against the very notion of OAuth.  OAuth means the user authorizes your application to work on their behalf, and you're suggesting an end-around that removes the user's choice from the equation.

Comment: you did read the question right? **Is there any way with Twitter to get the auth code without having to go through Twitter and being redirected back to the source page**

Comment: Yep, I read it.  But I wanted to make sure they realized they were explicitly breaking the terms of use of Twitter, so they weren't surprised if Twitter decided to disable their key.